# Unnormal exception in Date class in Zend Framework 2.0

Tags: php, zend-framework, date, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework **2.0** for my application. It's a beta version now. I need to convert datetime from one format to another. But I get the next unnormal exception: `The given path needs to be a directory`. In ZF 1.11 it works fine but not in 2.0. My simple code:

```
$date = new \Zend\Date\Date('29.12.2011 14:53:43', 'd.M.y H:m:s');
echo $date->get('y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you include the full exception message and stack trace if available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it could be an issue with the autoloader, out of interest what happens if you require in the Zend_Date class manually with `require('/path/to/library/Zend/Date.php')` or similar?

Comment: Thank you for interest. But problem was in `resources` folder.

Comment: Sorry, it was a my mistake. I forgot to upload folder resources to vendor/ZendFramework directory.